# Microblaze, declare data array with address values;

Tags: assembly, switch-statement, xilinx, microblaze

I'm trying to make a switch (jump) table for Microblaze CPU, which looks like

```
// Declaring offset table
.byte .L3-.L.Base, .L2-.L.Base, .L1-.L.Base, .L0-.L.Base

// ...
// calculating & reading offset into reg
br reg

.L3: //case 3
    ...
.L2: //case 2
    ...
.L1: //case 1
    ...
.L0: //case 0
```

The problem is that offset table is filled with zeroes. That's true when data types are 'byte' or 'short'. When data type is 'int' table is filled with correct values.

How should such an offset table be declared to be filled with correct byte values?

Thanks.